# Output SQL from an ActiveRecord migration without executing it (not rails!)

Tags: ruby, activerecord

*There's a bunch of questions out there similar to this one that talk about rails plugins as a solution - but I'm not using rails, read on for more*

I have a Rakefile in a sinatra project which allows me to `rake db:migrate`. It'll do my migration perfectly, but I'd like to pass that a flag (or write a new rake task) which does the same thing, but outputs the SQL to STDOUT and *doesn't* commit the changes to the database. Does anyone know how to do this?

My first thought was to try ActiveRecord logging and see if I could get the SQL out at all, but that doesn't work! Any ideas?

```
namespace :db do
    task :migrate_sql do
        require 'logger'

        ActiveRecord::Base.logger = Logger.new(STDOUT)

        Rake::Task['db:migrate'].invoke

        # This does the migration and doesn't output SQL - so no good!
    end
end
```

Comment: could you write the db:migrate task code? at least the relevant part

Comment: It's the standard stuff, implemented with `require "sinatra/activerecord/rake"`

Comment: Might `rake --run-dry` put you in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

I think there isn't any easy way to do it, for the following reasons:

1. `up`, `down`, and `change` are methods which execute other methods; there isn't a global migration query string that gets built and executed
2. neither the statements methods (`add_column`, etc) expose their statements as strings; as I  understand, they are implemented as connection adapter methods, and for example the mysql adapter has a [add_column_sql method](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/3-2-stable/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter.rb#L599), while the [postgresql adapter](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/3-2-stable/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb) does not, and its sql is a variable inside its `add_column` method

So, if you really need this functionality, I think your best option is to copy the sql from the log.